# How do I use Tensorflow's Estimator API to do distributed training?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/estimators) says:

> You can run Estimators-based models on a local host or on a
>   distributed multi-server environment without changing your model.
>   Furthermore, you can run Estimators-based models on CPUs, GPUs, or
>   TPUs without recoding your model.

Is there documentation to explain how to run an Estimator in a distributed multi-server environment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tensorflow documentation for tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/train_and_evaluate) explains one method for running `tf.estimator` in a distributed environment, which simply requires setting the `TF_CONFIG` environment variable appropriately.